# How can I disable voice commands when double pressing the home button on the Galaxy S 2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, voice-command

On Samsung Galaxy S2 (not rooted) everytime I accidently double press the home button, the voice command app comes up.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have installed Cyanogenmod 9 and this does not happen anymore. I don't think, this problem can be solved via settings of Samsungs Android version

Answer (score 5):

For a non-rooted phone, this is the best I have found:

- Double-tap, select Menu, Settings
- Voice Talk Seetings -> Speak Prompts: *uncheck*

Now if you double-tap, a short sound will be heard, but you won't hear the "What would you like to do?" anymore.

Comment: So double tab started the voice input, right? I need to ask, because I have Cyanogen Mod now. If this setting is inside the voice input app, I had to accept some terms of use from Samsung, but I didn't want to.

Comment: Yes, that's right. That setting is inside Voice Input so you need to open it in order to change that setting as far as I know.

Comment: So I have to accept terms of use for the software I don't want to use to disable it. Good job, Samsung ...

Answer (score 4):

I have disabled it using App-Freeze on [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup). This works well, and is entirely reversible, but appears to require both the Pro key (paid) and root.

A possible alternative would be removing it using either the terminal or ADB. The apk in question is /system/app/VoiceToGo.apk (com.vlingo.client.samsung), and my phone hasn't had a problem with it having been disabled. I would recommend backing it up, though, on the off chance.

Comment: Unfortunatly my phone is not rooted :/

Comment: This totally disables the voice input. OP only wants to disable launching of it by double pressing the home button.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how would one go about "removing" the apk? Does this also require root?

Answer (score 4):

[From an article on WordPress](http://kwatog.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/disabling-vlingo-voice-command-on-samsung-galaxy-s-ii/),

> 1. Install [Go Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) from Google Play.
> 2. Open the app drawer.
> 3. Press and hold on the blue voice command icon until it starts shaking.
> 4. Click on the **"X"** button and choose uninstall. Follow the instructions.
> 5. Optionally, you can uninstall Go Launcher.

Comment: This totally disables the voice input. OP only wants to disable launching of it by double pressing the home button.

Answer (score 2):

Double press the menu key in the S Voice application, go to Settings, and disable starting S Voice via double pressing the home button.

Comment: In the voice command settings there is no option to disable starting voice command via double pressing home button.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the following steps to disable `Voice Command` on ICS:

1. From the `home screen` go to `Settings` then `Applications`.
2. Find and select `Voice Command` in the `Downloaded` or `All` tabs
3. If the `Disable` option appears - select and then `ok`. It will not prompt again.
4. If not, select `Clear data` and then `ok`. The next time you mistakenly double click do not confirm the Samsung Disclaimer but select the back button instead.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded my S2 to ICS and continued facing the same problem.. The solution for the problem is Settings -> Language and Input -> Keyboard and input methods. Make sure Google voice typing is unchecked... Problem solved...

Comment: This totally disables the voice input. OP only wants to disable launching of it by double pressing the home button.

Comment: Totally disabling the voice input would be okay. I can't remember I ever used it.

Comment: this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

On [Droid Razr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_Razr), running ICS, it is under Accessibility, in the system settings menu:

Scroll to the bottom and you should see a double tap home launch field, click it and it will allow you to set it to "none".

Comment: On the Samsung SGS2 with the original OS there was no setting like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the S2, but I've just discovered that for the Galaxy Note, there's a setting "Launch voice talk" (launch by double-tapping home) that only appears when Vlingo is set as the voice recognition engine. If you choose Google, the option goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the voice command:

- open *settings → voice talk settings → motion*
- then uncheck double tap option 
  or
- uncheck motion activation altogether.

Comment: This "double tap" option has nothing to do with double pressing the home button